# xml against xsd in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, xsd

The below are the xml files I need to validate against an xsd file.

**XML File 1**

```
<ROOT  ElementType="1" >
    <ELEMENT_ONE>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_ONE>
    <ELEMENT_ONE>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_ONE>
</ROOT>
```

**XML File 2**

```
<ROOT  ElementType="2" >
    <ELEMENT_TWO>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_TWO>
    <ELEMENT_TWO>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_TWO>
</ROOT>
```

**XML File 3**

```
<ROOT  ElementType="3" >
    <ELEMENT_THREE>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_THREE>
</ROOT>
```

**XML File 4**

```
<ROOT  ElementType="4" >
    <ELEMENT_FOUR>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_FOUR>
</ROOT>
```

**XML File 5**

```
<ROOT  ElementType="5" >
    <ELEMENT_FIVE>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_FIVE>
</ROOT>
```

**XML File 6**

```
<ROOT  ElementType="6" >
    <ELEMENT_ONE>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_ONE>
    <ELEMENT_TWO>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_TWO>
    <ELEMENT_FIVE>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_FIVE>
    <ELEMENT_ONE>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_ONE>
    <ELEMENT_TWO>
        .
        .
        .
    </ELEMENT_TWO>
</ROOT>
```

Below is the xsd file against which the above xml files need to be validated.

```
<xsd:element name = "ROOT">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element ref = "agent:ELEMENT_ONE"  minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs = "unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element ref = "agent:ELEMENT_TWO"  minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs = "unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element ref = "agent:ELEMENT_THREE"  minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs = "1"/>
                <xsd:element ref = "agent:ELEMENT_FOUR"  minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs = "1"/>
                <xsd:element ref = "agent:ELEMENT_FIVE"  minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs = "1"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attribute name = "ElementType" use = "required">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="3"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="4"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="5"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="6"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

The above xsd validation works fine for cases 1 to 5. XML File 6 can have any number ELEMENT_ONE OR ELEMENT_TWO OR just one ELEMENT_FIVE. How can I include case 6 in the xsd validation?

If I cannot include case 6 in this xsd file, then is there a better schema to handle the above scenario?

Thank you all in advance for your feed back.

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.0, there is no way to restrict the schema of `<ROOT>` based on the value of it's defined attribute `ElementType`. The problem is akin to trying to define a word using the word itself as part of the definition.

The best you can do is:

```
<xsd:element name = "ROOT">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:choice>
                    <xsd:element ref="agent:ELEMENT_ONE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="agent:ELEMENT_TWO" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="agent:ELEMENT_THREE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="agent:ELEMENT_FOUR" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="agent:ELEMENT_FIVE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="agent:ELEMENT_ONE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element ref="agent:ELEMENT_TWO" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element ref="agent:ELEMENT_FIVE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:choice>

        <xsd:attribute name = "ElementType" use = "required">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="3"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="4"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="5"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="6"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Then, you'll have to separately validate that the "correct schema" is used based on the value of the `ElementType` attribute that was provided.

Note that what you want to do may be possible in XSD 1.1.

Comment: I have tried the above xsd file and I get the following error:

Comment: Multiple definition of element 'http://whatever':Element_ONE' causes the content model to become ambiguous. A content model must be formed such that during validation of an element information item sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly or implicitly therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence.

Comment: Hmm, ok. But as I said before, this isn't really a supported scenario for XSD 1.0. I've heard rumblings that XSD 1.1 may allow you to do something like this. If I think of anything else (or can make something like the above work), I'll be sure to come back here and edit my answer for you.